# Angular UI router - Promises and recursive redirection issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, promise, infinite-loop

**EDIT x2**

Following your suggestion, I made a lot of changes.

I made (i think?) a real promise this time but had a few issues.

What you suggested did not work at some point for this :

```
     // If it is, return true
     else {
         console.log('Valid token');
         return deferred.resolve(true);
     }
}
// If there's no valid token, return false
else {
     console.log('No token');
     $localStorage.$reset();
     $state.go('login');
     return deferred.reject(false);
}
```

I had to change this to :

```
     // If it is, return true
     else {
         console.log('Valid token');
         deferred.resolve(true);      // Removed "return"
     }
}
// If there's no valid token, return false
else {
     console.log('No token');
     $localStorage.$reset();
     $state.go('login');
     deferred.reject(false);          // Removed "return"
}
```

I finally made it for the redirection I expected now my promise works...

```
// Watching login page
$transitions.onStart({to: 'login'}, function (trans) {

    // Injecting the authentication service
    var auth = trans.injector().get('AuthService');

    // returning the promise with handlers
    return auth.isAuthenticated().then(function (res) {

        // If the token is valid, redirect to the dashboard
        return trans.router.stateService.target('dashboard.home');
    }, function(e) {

        // If the token is invalid or missing, keep the login page
        return trans.router.stateService.target;
    });
});

// Watching the dashboard private page  
$transitions.onStart({to: 'dashboard.**'}, function (trans) {

    // Injecting the authentication service
    var auth = trans.injector().get('AuthService');

    // returning the promise with handlers
    return auth.isAuthenticated().then(function (res) {

        // If the user is correctly identified, do nothing
        return trans.router.stateService.target;
    }, function (e) {

        // If the token is invalid or missing, deleting datas
        $localStorage.$reset();

        // Setting error message
        $localStorage.loginError = {'token_expired': true};

        // Redirecting to the login page
        return trans.router.stateService.target('login');
    })
});
```

Comment: you should try to use 'resolve' with state(UI Router), in which you will actually authenticate user before entering to that state. In above given code, you are not returning promise.

Comment: Hi Shaiilendra, I'm a bit confused with the 1.0 beta 2 version of this add-on, I find the new Transition system a bit complex... Do you have any example to help me handle this?

In fact my login is working fine. Checking and updating token is ok as well. My issue is I want to prevent people accessing dashboard if not authenticated AND allow them to access directly if they still have a renewable token to the dashboard without login-in.

This is where this fail. If I only use the first one (delog user) it's ok. If i put the two, I go into an infinite loop and can't see why !

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning promise in your `isAuthenticated` method and also remove `state.go('login')` from `isAuthenticated` method because it may cause redirection issue. This method should be like as-

```
 vm.isAuthenticated = function () {
                 var deferred = $q.defer();
                var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

                // Getting token datas
                var exp = vm.getClaimsFromToken();

                console.log('Expire dans : '  + (exp.exp - ts) + 's');

                // Check if hte token exist
                if ($localStorage.token) {

                    // Check if it is still valid
                    if (ts > exp.exp) {

                        // Refresh the token
                        return vm.refreshToken().then(
                            function(res) {
                                if (res) {
                                    console.log('Refreshing Really Done');
                                    console.log(res);
                                    return deferred.resolve(res);
                                }
                            },
                            // Handle error
                            function (e) {
                                if (!e) {
                                    console.log('Refreshing Failed');
                                    $localStorage.$reset();
                                   // $state.go('login');
                                    return deferred.reject(e);
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                    // If it is, return true
                    else {
                        console.log('Valid token');
                        return deferred.resolve(true);
                    }
                }
                // If there's no valid token, return false
                else {
                    console.log('No token');
                    $localStorage.$reset();
                   // $state.go('login');
                    return deferred.reject(false);
                }
            return deferred.promise;
            };
```

Here, method is returning promise first `return deferred.promise` and based on your method's logic, it is resolving or rejecting promise.

Now handle redirection in such a way-

```
// Watching login page
$transitions.onStart({to: 'login'}, function (trans) {

    // Injecting the authentication service
    var auth = trans.injector().get('AuthService');

    // returning the promise with handlers
    auth.isAuthenticated().then(function (res) { //remove return keyword

        // If the token is valid, redirect to the dashboard
        return trans.router.stateService.target('dashboard.home');
    }, function(e) {

        // If the token is invalid or missing, keep the login page
      //  return trans.router.stateService.target; //removed this line
    });
});

// Watching the dashboard private page  
$transitions.onStart({to: 'dashboard.**'}, function (trans) {

    // Injecting the authentication service
    var auth = trans.injector().get('AuthService');

    // returning the promise with handlers
    auth.isAuthenticated().then(function (res) { //remove return keyword

        // If the user is correctly identified, do nothing
       // return trans.router.stateService.target; //removed this line
    }, function (e) {

        // If the token is invalid or missing, deleting datas
        $localStorage.$reset();

        // Setting error message
        $localStorage.loginError = {'token_expired': true};

        // Redirecting to the login page
        return trans.router.stateService.target('login');
    })
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my redirection loop. I still get a loop going on with the .run $transition options. Can't find why. I did all the changes you suggested.

If you could look at my .run statement and see where I get this kind of loop things... I should maybe make a check to see from where the redirection is coming to  avoid one of the "before" statement looping with the other one but this exceed my comprehension as it where working with the old state events with older versions of UI Router.

Comment: @FrançoisH. I have modified code. Check it now, I have changed logic in both parts to handle authentications. Let me know if you still found any issue.